# tcsh couldn't echo word with square bracket

Tags: tcsh

I have a list of data below

```
%cat data
a
b[1]
c[2]
d
```

and i try to echo each line using the command below:

```
%foreach aa ( `cat data` )
foreach? echo $aa
foreach? end
a
echo: No match
```

can somebody explain what is going on with the echo cmd and how to fix it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
echo $aa
```

and `$aa` contains `b[1]`, the shell tries to handle the `[` and `]` metacharacters after it expands the value of the variable. Since you (probably) have nothing in your current directory that matches `b[1]`, you get an error.

You need to quote the variable reference.  Replace

```
echo $aa
```

by either

```
echo "$aa"
```

or

```
echo $aa:q
```

(The `:q` syntax is specific to csh and tcsh; double quotes work similarly in most shells, including csh-derived shells and sh-derived shells like `bash`).

Comment: `[]` are globbing metacharacters, and the shell interprets them, as you said. Could you explain two points regarding that? Firstly, the standard behavior in that case is to leave the string alone instead of an error. Secondly, how does `echo` know about the fact that there was a substitution if the shell does it before commands are called? It is indicated in the error message that `echo` is the program returning the error. Is this some old shell behavior?

Comment: @Larry: tcsh doesn't just "leave the string alone". If there's a substitution error, it's reported as an error. If you're talking about "the standard behavior", you're likely referring to the POSIX shell standard, supported (mostly) by sh, ksh, bash, et al (and many sh-derived shells have options to change the behavior). `echo` doesn't know that there was an error. The shell itself inserts the command name into the error message. For example, in tcsh `nosuchcommand nosuchfile*.txt` prints `nosuchcommand: No match.` (In bash, it prints `nosuchcommand: command not found`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! At my workplace, tcsh is configured differently and there is no error. At my home PC, it really does throw the error you mentioned. Bash does it a little differently though, after setting `shopt -s failglob`. `/bin/echo bla?` -> `bash: no match: bla?`